# php sign in using twitter

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I try to do signin using epi twitter, here is the code

```
    $consumerKey = $this->consumerKey ;
    $consumerSecret = $this->consumerSecret;        
    include 'application/libraries/twitter-oauth/EpiCurl.php';
    include 'application/libraries/twitter-oauth/EpiOAuth.php';
    include 'application/libraries/twitter-oauth/EpiTwitter.php';
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $Twitter = new EpiTwitter($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);

    if(isset($_GET['oauth_token']) || (isset($_COOKIE['oauth_token']) && isset($_COOKIE['oauth_token_secret'])))
    {
              // process
    }
    elseif(isset($_GET['denied']))
    {
        // user denied access
        echo 'You must sign in through twitter first';
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        // user not logged in
        echo 'You are not logged in';
        exit;
    }
```

but always the response is "you're not logged ini" although I've sign ini to twitter in other page.
Is there something wrong with my code?

Appreciate for any help.

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you authenticate the user, save their authToken and authTokenSecret.
Either in a session/database/cookie, it's up to you.

Then when you create a new instance of your EpiTwitter class, pass those 2 new arguments swell.

```
$Twitter = new EpiTwitter($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $userAuthToken, $userTokenSecret);
```

See the arguments for the __construct function you're calling,

```
  public function __construct($consumerKey = null, $consumerSecret = null, $oauthToken = null, $oauthTokenSecret = null)
  {
    parent::__construct($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, self::EPITWITTER_SIGNATURE_METHOD);
    $this->setToken($oauthToken, $oauthTokenSecret);
  }
```

Comment: cmiiw, isn't we get $userAuthToken from $Twitter = new EpiTwitter..., why we include in param?